# How to switch an array to object with specify keys by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H']
```

And I wanna convert to an object like this:

```
{
  group0: {
    first: 'A',
    last: 'B'
  },
  group1: {
    first: 'C',
    last: 'D'
  },
  group2: {
    first: 'E',
    last: 'F'
  },
  group3: {
    first: 'G',
    last: 'H'
  }
}
```

What will I do?

Comment: Could you please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Loop through the array, Use the `index` to create `groupx`  and split the string at `" "` and add properties to nested object?

Comment: There are various functions you can use: [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) + [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and your brains. With these, you can solve the problem pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` like below

```js
var arr = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H'];

const result = arr.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    const [first, last] = item.split(' ');
    obj[`group${index}`] = {
       first,
       last,
    };
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy to understand solution using for loop and array split method.

```js
var arr = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H'];

var res = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  var splittedArray = arr[i].split(' ');
  var first = splittedArray[0];
  var second = splittedArray[1];
  var key = `group${i}`;
  var value = {
    first: first,
    second: second
  };
  res[key] = value;

}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var arr = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H'];
var index = 0;
var output = arr.reduce((result, current) => {
  var splitArr = current.split(' ');
  result['group'+index++] = {
      first: splitArr[0],
      last: splitArr[1],
  }
  return result;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `index++` doesn't work and I was first to answer 

Comment: for `index++` you can check the result. And yes you are the first but my answer was just after few seconds.

Comment: @MaximeHelen What makes you think index++ wouldn't work here? It is pointless if you consider that reduce gives you the index, but it will work this way.

Comment: `++` is applied after concatenation. Look at the output, `group0` is not incremented.  The correct way to do so would be `'group'+(++index)`. This is also not what is expected from the question.

Comment: have you seen any difference in your and mine output?

Comment: Yes no difference, although your code is incrementing index after concatenation, for nothing

Comment: Gracias. I am grinding the ladder ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
var arr = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H'];
var converted = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitStr = arr[i].split(" ");
  converted["group" + i] = {
    first: splitStr[0],
    last: splitStr[1]
  };
}
console.log(converted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the strings and get objects for mapping.

```js
var data = ['A B', 'C D', 'E F', 'G H'],
    result = data.map(s => (([first, last]) => ({ first, last }))(s.split(' ')));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```